# Late Answers Review - manually flag posts for deletion - the "Recommend Deletion" button is broken

Tags: discussion, flagging

#### TL;DR

If you thought, as I did, that the **Recommend Deletion** button, in the **Late Answers** review, deletes posts... well, it doesn't.

***If an answer merits deletion***, then, in addition to selecting the **Recommend Deletion** radio button, also raise a flag against the answer, before hitting submit.

Actually, you *could* also raise the flag *after* hitting submit, it doesn't really matter... basically, just make sure that you raise a flag.

---

#### Links

I saw this, [Recommend Deletion option in Late Answers review queue does nothing - please flag posts that should be deleted](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19822/348964).

The actual bug has ben raised on Meta, [Remove (or rename) the ineffective "recommend deletion" option from Late Answers queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371918/280335).

Please see the links above for the full details.